# Command run in terminal but not in QProcess while PATHs are inserted

Tags: qt, path, qprocess, openfoam

I want to run a command in Ubuntu via Qt using QProcess.
My command is `fluent3DMeshToFoam <mesh address>`
and when I run it into terminal its OK and produces sum output and files in a specific location. But I have problem with running it using QProcess.

I have noticed that I should add the path of `fluent3DMeshToFoam` to ProcessEnvironment of my QProcess object. So I did:

```
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("PATH" , "<path of fluent3DMeshToFoam>");
myProcess.setProcessEnvironment(env);
myProcess.start("fluent3DMeshToFoam" , QStringList() << "<mesh address>");
myProcess.waitForFinished(-1);
```

I connected `readyRead()` and `errorOccurred()` signals and after I run, the `errorOccurred` signal emits and the following error shows:

```
execve: No such file or directory
```

I searched alot and could not find out where the problem is.
thanks.

Comment: How did you install fluent3DMeshToFoam?

Comment: @eyllanesc Its  a part of the program OpenFOAM5 and I have installed it in offline mode using following link:
https://openfoam.org/download/5-0-source/

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the path correctly?  Also note that `QProcess::insert("PATH",...` will *replace* any existing variable named `PATH`.  e.g. if I'd installed `fluent3DMeshToFoam` at `/opt/bin/fluent3DMeshToFoam` I'd use something like `env.insert("PATH", env.value("PATH") + ":/opt/bin")`.

Comment: @G.M. I changed my code as you mentioned but the error still occurs. Also note that when I run `echo $PATH` in terminal, the installation path of `fluent3DMeshToFoam` is available but when I `qDebug` the `env.value("PATH")` before `env.insert(...)` the path of `fluent3DMeshToFoam` is not available.

Comment: This thread may be useful: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27152-Problems-launching-a-windows-exe-from-Qt-(using-QProcess)

Comment: @m7913d Unfortunately it does not worked for me because I am in linux and their problem arounded addressing in windows.

Comment: As stated in the mentioned thread, I think your problem is that you have to include the full path when calling `QProgram::start`: ["QProcess doesn't understand the "PATH" variable as you think it would. You are passing PATH to environment of the application, meaning that it will be effective once the application is launched. It won't take part in searching for the application to be launched. You need to provide an absolute path to QProcess."](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/27152-Problems-launching-a-windows-exe-from-Qt-(using-QProcess))

Comment: @m7913d I used a full path as you mentioned and now there is no output or error. It should be noted that `fluent3DMeshToFoam ` is a `elf` precompiled binary file. I also tried`/bin/sh` to run it but still nothing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

After a-lot of searches, finally I found-out that there was a problem with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which does not considered by Qt.

Without any using of `setProcessEnvironment(...)`, I open terminal and `export` the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` just before running it as follows:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
exec "./my_app"
```

Then my_app is aware of all libraries stored `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`